# How to monitor local variables in STAN?

Tags: mcmc, stan

I'm currently trying to port some JAGS models to STAN. I get some strange errors "stan::prob::exponential_log(N4stan5agrad3varE): Random variable is nan:0, but must not be nan!" and to debug those I would like to know the the values of some local parameters.

In JAGS I can set up monitors for any variable. STAN only monitors parameters. But parameter cannot have assignments (if I understand it correctly).

So how do I monitor intermediate variables?

I also paste the model code, in case someone sees a stupid mistake I make. Note, however, that I'm aware that the same model can be formulated as the CDF of a double exponential (with two rates). This is a simplified form of what I plan.

```
Model:

data {
    int y[11]; // 
    int reps[11];
    real soas[11]; 

}
parameters {
    real<lower=0.001,upper=0.200> v1;
    real<lower=0.001,upper=0.200> v2;

}


model {
    int dif[11,96];
    real cf[11];

    real p[11];

    real t1[11,96];
    real t2[11,96];

    for (i in 1:11){
        for (r in 1:reps[i]){     
            t1[i,r]  ~ exponential(v1);
            t2[i,r]  ~ exponential(v2);
            dif[i,r] <-  (t1[i,r]+soas[i]<=(t2[i,r]));

            }
        cf[i] <- sum(dif[i]);
        p[i]  <-cf[i]/reps[i];
        y[i] ~ binomial(reps[i],p[i]); 
    }

}
```

Here is some dummy data:

```
psy_dat = { 
         'soas' :  numpy.array(range(-100,101,20)),
            'y' :  [47, 46, 62, 50, 59, 47, 36, 13, 7, 2, 1],
         'reps' :  [48, 48, 64, 64, 92, 92, 92, 64, 64, 48, 48]
          }
```

Answer (score 7):

In this particular case, the problem is that `t1` (and `t2` for that matter) are initialized to `NaN` and not changed to anything before you utilize the `exponential` likelihood. My guess is that `t1` and `t2` need to be in a `generated quantities` block if you intend to draw them from their posterior predictive distribution.

To answer your question as stated, you can use a `print()` statement within the model block to debug a problematic Stan program. And if you really want to store intermediates, then you need to declare and define them within a `transformed parameters` block of the Stan program.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. No sampling can be done in the generated quantities block. So I tried to sample the values in the model block, assign them to variables in the generated quantities block and tried to use those again in the model block. But this is not possible either. I will try a few other things, but any ideas or hints are highly welcome.

Comment: Oh one more thing: I also get this most likely related warning: `Warning (non-fatal): Left-hand side of sampling statement (~) contains a non-linear transform of a parameter or local variable.
 You must call increment_log_prob() with the log absolute determinant of the Jacobian of the transform. Sampling Statement left-hand-side expression:
    get_base1(get_base1(t1,i,"t1",1),r,"t1",2) ~ exponential_log(...)´ which I can't make sense of. However, all this doesn't have anything to do with monitoring variables, so I guess I should start a new topic with that.

Comment: You can't really "sample" in any block. In Stan, the `variable ~ distribution(arguments);` construction means "tack the logarithm of `distribution` evaluated at `variable` and `arguments` onto the log-posterior distribution when evaluating Metropolis proposals". In generated quantities, the `~` is disallowed, but you can do `t1 <- exponential_rng(v1);`. It may be easier to just post your JAGS program and ask how to translate it to a Stan program.

Comment: Many thanks again. By now I think the problem is that the sum of the Booleans that generates the cf leads to Stan being unable to calculate the gradient for the HMC proposals (I posted a question regarding this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963759/stan-version-of-a-jags-model-which-includes-a-sum-of-discrete-values-is-it-pos-)