# Stan version of a JAGS model which includes a sum of discrete values - Is it possible?

Tags: bayesian, mcmc, stan

I was trying to run this model in Stan. I have a running JAGS version of it (that returns highly autocorrelated parameters) and I know how to formulate it as CDF of a double exponential (with two rates), which would probably run without problems. However, I would like to use this version as a starting point for similar but more complex models.

By now I have the suspicion that a model like this is not possible in Stan. Maybe because of the discreteness introduces by taking the sum of a Boolean value, Stan may not be able to calculate gradients.

Does anyone know whether this is the case, or if I do something else in a wrong way in this model? I paste the errors I get below the model code.

Many thanks in advance
Jan

```
Model:

data {
    int y[11]; 
    int reps[11];
    real soas[11]; 

}
parameters {
    real<lower=0.001,upper=0.200> v1;
    real<lower=0.001,upper=0.200> v2;

}


model {
    real dif[11,96];
    real cf[11];

    real p[11];

    real t1[11,96];
    real t2[11,96];

    for (i in 1:11){
        for (r in 1:reps[i]){     
            t1[i,r]  ~ exponential(v1);
            t2[i,r]  ~ exponential(v2);
            dif[i,r] <-  (t1[i,r]+soas[i]<=(t2[i,r]));

            }
        cf[i] <- sum(dif[i]);
        p[i]  <-cf[i]/reps[i];
        y[i] ~ binomial(reps[i],p[i]); 
    }

}
```

Here is some dummy data:

```
psy_dat = { 
         'soas' :  numpy.array(range(-100,101,20)),
            'y' :  [47, 46, 62, 50, 59, 47, 36, 13, 7, 2, 1],
         'reps' :  [48, 48, 64, 64, 92, 92, 92, 64, 64, 48, 48]
          }
```

And here are the errors:

```
DIAGNOSTIC(S) FROM PARSER:
Warning (non-fatal): Left-hand side of sampling statement (~) contains a non-linear transform of a parameter or local variable.
You must call increment_log_prob() with the log absolute determinant of the Jacobian of the transform.
Sampling Statement left-hand-side expression:
get_base1(get_base1(t1,i,"t1",1),r,"t1",2) ~ exponential_log(...)
Warning (non-fatal): Left-hand side of sampling statement (~) contains a non-linear transform of a parameter or local variable.
You must call increment_log_prob() with the log absolute determinant of the Jacobian of the transform.
Sampling Statement left-hand-side expression:
get_base1(get_base1(t2,i,"t2",1),r,"t2",2) ~ exponential_log(...)
```

And at runtime:

```
Informational Message: The current Metropolis proposal is about to be rejected because of the following issue:
 stan::prob::exponential_log(N4stan5agrad3varE): Random variable is nan:0, but must not be nan!
 If this warning occurs sporadically, such as for highly constrained variable types like covariance matrices, then the sampler is fine,
but if this warning occurs often then your model may be either severely ill-conditioned or misspecified.
 Rejecting proposed initial value with zero density.


Initialization between (-2, 2) failed after 100 attempts. 
 Try specifying initial values, reducing ranges of constrained values, or   reparameterizing the model
```

Here is a working JAGS version of this model:

```
   model {
   for ( n in 1 : N  ) { 
     for (r in 1 : reps[n]){
       t1[r,n] ~ dexp(v1)
       t2[r,n] ~ dexp(v2)
       c[r,n] <- (1.0*((t1[r,n]+durs[n])<=t2[r,n]))
     } 
     p[n] <- max((min(sum(c[,n]) /  (reps[n]),0.99999999999999)),   1-0.99999999999999)) 
     y[n] ~ dbin(p[n],reps[n])
   }

   v1 ~ dunif(0.0001,0.2)
   v2 ~ dunif(0.0001,0.2)
   }
```

With regard to the min() and max(): See this post https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130978/observed-node-inconsistent-when-binomial-success-rate-exactly-one?noredirect=1#comment250046_130978.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not sure what model you are trying to estimate (it would be best if you post the JAGS code) but what you have above cannot work in Stan. Stan is closer to C++ in the sense that you have to declare and then define objects. In your Stan program, you have the two declarations

`real t1[11,96];
real t2[11,96];`

but no definitions of `t1` or `t2`. Consequently, they are initalized to `NaN` and when you do

`t1[i,r] ~ exponential(v1);`

that gets parsed as something like

`for(i in 1:11) for(r in 1:reps[i]) lp__ += log(v1) - v1 * NaN`

where `lp__` is an internal symbol that holds value of the log-posterior, which becomes NaN and it cannot do Metropolis-style updates of the parameters.

Perhaps you meant for `t1` and `t2` to be unknown parameters, in which case they should be declared in the `parameters` block. The following [EDITED] Stan program is valid and should work, but it might not be the program you had in mind (it does not make a lot of sense to me and the discontinuity in `dif` will probably preclude Stan from sampling from this posterior distribution efficiently).

`data {
    int<lower=1> N;
    int y[N];
    int reps[N];
    real soas[N];
}
parameters {
    real<lower=0.001,upper=0.200> v1;
    real<lower=0.001,upper=0.200> v2;
    real t1[N,max(reps)];
    real t2[N,max(reps)];
}
model {
    for (i in 1:N) {
        real dif[reps[i]];
        for (r in 1:reps[i]) {
            dif[r] <-  (t1[i,r]+soas[i]) <= t2[i,r];
        }
        y[i] ~ binomial(reps[i], (1.0 + sum(dif)) / (1.0 + reps[i]));
    }
    to_array_1d(t1)  ~ exponential(v1);
    to_array_1d(t2)  ~ exponential(v2);
}`

Comment: I tried exactly that (and verified by using your exact suggestions): This gives the same error.

I add the JAGS code to the original question.

Comment: I add the JAGS code to the original question. Note that I also tried the min()/max() thing ins Stan. And regarding what is modeled: It's the probability that one process finishes earlier than the other. Which, when expressed analytically, estimates very well in JAGS but in this form the chains are highly autocorrelated. I was hoping for Stan's HMC  to improve on that. The reason for expressing the model like this is that it is close to the processes physically assumed and would make it very easy to incorporate some more advanced mechanisms without deriving complicated analytical solution.

Comment: OK. Where does the 96 come from in the original code? Did you perhaps mean 92, which is the maximum of reps (I've changed the Stan code to reflect this assumption). Previously, when `dif[i]` was 96 elements long and you do `sum(dif[i])` when `reps[i] < 96`, you get `NaN` because the last (few) elments of `dif[i]` remain uninitialized. However, that still is not going to work well with Stan because of the disconitnuities. Can't the binomial probability be expressed analytically as the CDF of a shifted exponential with an upper bound of `t2[i,r]`?

Comment: 96 is supposed to be max(reps) - stupid mistake due to hard-coded values. And it was a good hint. After fixing it, the error remained, but I noticed the sum is (almost) always nan because dif contains nans whenever reps[i]<max(reps), which is case at many i's. For testing, I used 92 for reps[i] at all i, and the model is indeed being sampled right now. And yes it can be expressed successfully (at least in JAGS) using CDFs (e.g., a CDF of a double exp. to model both processes);  but see the original post regarding my motivation for this version. I'll be back after I looked at the posteriors ...